# Passing Text box value into string

Tags: jsp

I want to pass the value from the textbox to String Value How to Pass it? Anyone give me an example

User Textbox value is passed to the string as a value...How to do it?

Comment: @Engineer please don't use code spans (`like this`) to highlight text, it's only meant for code within sentences. For example, `<body>` is alright, but you shouldn't do something like `User textbox value`. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of All You Need a Programming language and you have to post code first then we can see your code and post solution.

You also have to provide some html code as well as destination i.e. where to send the data for further processing.

simple html code :

```
<body>
<form method ="post" action="addDateServlet">
 <input type="text" id="name" name="name"/>
 <input type="submit"/>
</form>
</body>
```

If you are using servlet then you have to make servlet entry in `web.xml` and if you are using `servlet 3.0` then no entry needed in `web.xml` you can directly use `webservlet annotation` and directly map action to it and further process data.

to get textbox data in servlet :

```
String name = request.getParamater("name"); //here "name" is name of html textbox
```

[full example with tutorial](http://www.beingjavaguys.com/2013/08/jsp-servlet-hello-world-example.html)

[Oracle tutorial with example](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnaeo.html)

Comment: @user3517990 - here is a link http://www.java-forums.org/jdbc/41463-insert-data-postgresql-database-using-jsp-servlets.html

Comment: @user3517990 - another example, instead of `mysql` you can use `postgresql` http://latest-technology-guide.blogspot.in/2013/03/java-jsp-servlet-database-connectivity-example.html

Comment: here is a connection tutorial http://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/how-do-connect-to-postgresql-with-jdbc-driver-java/

Comment: @user3517990 - why have to un-accept the answer ? Any problem ?